# Do you use a semicolon or colon before the word “that” in a sentence?

Tags: punctuation, semicolons, colons

I just wanted to ask if a semicolon or colon is appropriate before the word “that” in a sentence.

For example,

> I want to tell him that maybe it is the fact that I have been guarded every second of every minute of every hour of every day that I have been here; that I cannot even relieve myself when nature calls without my guards knowing.

This is from a book I read. This has itched my mind a lot since a semicolon isn’t supposed to be used when there is a dependent clause.

Comment: It's ambiguous quite apart from the punctuation chosen. The sentence is getting unwieldy, though I can understand the desire not to divide it into two. I'd use a dash followed by _tell him that_ or _the fact that_ to disambiguate.

Comment: The semicolon separates two relative clauses with the same referent (the fact): I want to tell him that maybe it is the fact (i) that I have been guarded ...here; (ii) that I cannot even relieve myself when nature calls.... As there are only two items in the list, I would use "and".

Answer (score 1):

I read the sentence as follows:

> I want to tell him that maybe it is the fact
>
> 1. that I have been guarded every second of every minute of every hour of every day that I have been here; [and]
> 2. that I cannot even relieve myself when nature calls without my guards knowing.

In other words, we simply have a list of two *that*-clauses that are connected by a conjunction, except that the conjunction itself has been omitted for effect.

I think the reason that the two items in the list are separated by a semicolon is that they are quite long. I believe this is one of the commonly accepted uses of a semicolon.

A semicolon would certainly be inappropriate if there were only one *that*-clause rather than a list of them. You definitely wouldn't write "I want to tell him that it is the fact; that I have been guarded every second I have been here."

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So if a sentence is long, we can use a semicolon to separate them? But I heard from another friend of mine that semicolons are only used when two clauses are independent. Colons, on the other hand, can be used when one of the clauses is dependent and used for emphasis(?) 
For example: “She made sure that everything was perfect: that all things were properly organized.” 
The second clause also starts with the word “that”. Now I’m confused which one to use. Do i only use colons when in need of emphasis and use semicolons when the sentence becomes too long?

Comment: According to this interpretation, the sentence is incomplete and therefore ungrammatical, as I claim in my reply: *I want to tell him that maybe it is the fact that X and Y that...?* The fact that the sentence appears in a book does not guarantee it is well written.

Comment: @Gustavson I'm not quite sure what you're saying. According to *my* interpretation of the sentence, it's a complete sentence, and it's grammatical, aside from two possible problems: the omission of the word "and" between the two list items, and the use of a semicolon where perhaps a comma should have been used.

Comment: @TannerSwett I don't understand the sense of saying: *I want to tell him that maybe it is the fact that I have been guarded all this time that I cannot even relieve myself when nature calls without my guards knowing* without a linker of reason for the clause that has been clefted: *I want to tell him that maybe it is DUE TO the fact that I have been guarded all this time that I cannot even relieve myself when nature calls without my guards knowing.*

Comment: @TannerSwett Can you use "it is the fact" alone to indicate reason? For example, would you say this is correct: *It is the fact that I am being supervised all the the time that I cannot do what I want* or would you rather say: *It is because I am being supervised all the time that I cannot do what I want*?

Comment: @Gustavson My interpretation is that this isn't a cleft sentence at all, nor does either clause provide a reason for the other one. I think that presumably, someone has asked the speaking character a question along the lines of "What are you so upset about?" The speaking character then gives two answers, which are essentially: "It (the thing I'm upset about) is the fact that I am guarded every second. It (the thing I'm upset about) is the fact that I can't even pee without my guards knowing."

Comment: @TannerSwett Oh, I see. I saw a relationship of reason between the character not being able to pee unseen and his being guarded all the time. And I saw the semicolon as an exaggerated pause between what I thought was the clefted and the main clause. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

That should probably be a comma. [Purdue OWL (Online Writing Lab)](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/punctuation/commas/extended_rules_for_commas.html) says

> 7. Use a comma near the end of a sentence to separate contrasted coordinate elements or
>    to indicate a distinct pause or shift.
>
> He was merely ignorant, not stupid.
>
> The speaker seemed innocent, even gullible.

There's a general rule that you can replace most commas by semicolons if the phrases they are separating are long enough that the sentence would be confusing if you left them as commas. However, in this case, I don't believe this sentence is at all confusing with a comma.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect it’s a question of style, however the word ‘that’ in this situation replaces the expository colon.

*I want to tell him: maybe it is the fact that I have been*

Answer (score -1):

I find the sentence:

- I want to tell him that maybe it is the fact that I have been guarded every second of every minute of every hour of every day that I have been here; that I cannot even relieve myself when nature calls without my guards knowing.

faulty from the point of view of grammar and punctuation.

The clause "that I cannot even relieve myself when nature calls without my guards knowing" is the main clause in a cleft sentence. What wants to be emphasized by means of the cleft structure is the reason why the person cannot feel free even when nature calls, and this is why the sentence is defective: there should be a conjunction or preposition of reason before "the fact that":

- I want to tell him that maybe it is **because of / due to** the fact that I have been guarded every second of every minute of every hour of every day that I have been here that I cannot even relieve myself when nature calls without my guards knowing.

or

- I want to tell him that maybe it is **because** I have been guarded every second of every minute of every hour of every day that I have been here that I cannot even relieve myself when nature calls without my guards knowing.

The semicolon before the main clause is definitely wrong. There could be a comma, but not a semicolon or a colon. We should consider that the sentence stems from:

- I want to tell him that I cannot even relieve myself when nature calls without my guards knowing because I have been guarded every second of every minute of every hour of every day that I have been here => I want to tell him that it is for this reason that I cannot relieve myself.

Comment: This answer would make sense if the quote were saying that the writer's inability to relieve themself was due to being guarded, but that doesn't seem to be the case: rather, the "that I cannot even relieve myself \[...]" part is another reason for "it" (presumably "my problem that I've just described"), an amplification of "that I have been guarded every second \[...]" - and in that case the grammar is fine; some would prefer a comma to the semicolon but I'd argue that the semicolon is fine as is.

Comment: @psmears That's why my claim is that the sentence is also grammatically faulty -- it should read: I want to tell him that maybe it is **because** I have been guarded ... that I cannot even relieve myself... To me, the writer's intention was to express reason.

Comment: The word "even" is a big clue that shows that that is not the correct interpretation - for the word "even" to be used this way ("\[A], can't even \[B]") the second half (B) has to be a specific/extreme example of the first half (A). If the second half is giving a reason there seems to be nothing that the "even" is referring back to. Also the first half doesn't really make sense as a cause of the second half (why would having been observed constantly in the past mean you can't now wee without someone knowing?)